# Now() in where clause in MDX query

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I am trying to find out all the records between current date -30 days. But not able to write a MDX filter for this. My current query is:

```
 WITH
  SET [~FILTER] AS
     {[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].Members}
 SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].Members}
    SELECT
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS]} ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
   FROM [SALES_ORDER]
   WHERE [~FILTER]
```

which is fetching all the records.

Comment: Tell us some more on how dates are stored in your date table. Is it pre-populated with some ranges or are there dates only for days of transaction? Is today's date the last date?

Comment: Hi Sourav,
I have added date in yyyyMMdd format. it is pre-populated  table. For an example  WITH
  SET [~FILTER] AS
     {[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[20140220]}
 SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].Members}
    SELECT
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS]} ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
   FROM [SALES_ORDER]
   WHERE [~FILTER] with this query I am able to fetch the record with the transaction happened on 2014-02-20, so using the above query I wanted to fetch all the records between now()-30 days. 
Thanks,

Comment: @malay did either sourav or myself answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of finding today in the AdvWrks cube along with the 30 preceding days:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today (AW)] AS 
    '2007' + Right([Measures].[Key for Today],4) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today (AW)] + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    ) 
  SET [Last30Days] AS 
    [Today].Item(0).Item(0).Lag(30) : [Today].Item(0).Item(0) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[Last30Days] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Results in this:

[image]

So if we wanted to amend the above so that we only get Internet Sales Amount for the past 30 days:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today (AW)] AS 
    '2007' + Right([Measures].[Key for Today],4) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today (AW)] + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    ) 
  SET [Last30Days] AS 
    [Today].Item(0).Item(0).Lag(30) : [Today].Item(0).Item(0) 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[Last30Days] AS 
    Aggregate([Last30Days]) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Date].[Calendar].[All].[Last30Days];
```

Applying to your scenario the above would look something like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    ) 
  SET [~FILTER] AS 
    [Today].Item(0).Item(0).Lag(30) : [Today].Item(0).Item(0) 
  MEMBER [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[~FILTERaggregated] AS 
  //MEMBER [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[All].[~FILTERaggregated] AS //<<if above is throwing an exception then try this instead
    Aggregate([~FILTER]) 
  SET [~ROWS] AS 
    {
      [Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].MEMBERS
    } 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SALES_ORDER]
WHERE 
  [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[~FILTERaggregated];
```

Comment: `[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[~FILTER];`? Will this work?

Comment: @SouravA this may be better `[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[All].[~FILTER]`

Comment: You have put a set alias in place of a member name. Will it not throw an error?

Comment: @SouravA no - it is fine to have a set and a calculated member with the same name

Comment: `[Some Dim].[Some Hier].[Alias of a set of members]` is my concern.

Comment: @SouravA did you try testing your concern? It's fine - for readability I can change if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The below should work as your date "filter"

```
Filter 
    ( 
     [Created_Date].[Created_Hir].[Created_On].Members, 
     DateDiff 
        ( 
         "d", 
         CDate([Created_Date].[Created_Hir].MEMBER_VALUE), 
         Now() 
        ) <=30 
    )
```

**Don't** use named set as you have in the example if you don't want to run into performance issues.

Let me know if the performance is not good enough.

Comment: Thanks Sourav For your quick response,

Comment: Thanks Sourav For your quick response,
I have tried the above query but it is giving me 
 this error
Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'DateDiff(<String>, <Numeric Expression>, <DateTime>)'

Also when I tried do query on [Created_Date.Created_Hir].CurrentMember.Value it is throwing 
Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature '{<Numeric Expression>}'

also just wanted to tell than in my backend I am using vertica as a data base but vertica has datediff function.

Comment: Mondrian is a pain in the *** when it comes to the functions it supports. Let me check the Mondrian documentation for an equivalent function.

Comment: Caused by: mondrian.olap.fun.MondrianEvaluationException: mondrian.olap.InvalidArgumentException: Mondrian Error:Invalid parameter. expression parameter of CDate function must be formatted correctly (0.0)

I'll also google for this error. If you find anything please post it here.

Comment: Wow. Try removing cdate over th 3rd parameter. I put it there as a precautionary measure.

Comment: this is my query
WITH
SET [~FILTER] AS
   Filter
   (
    [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].Members,
    DateDiff
         (
          "d", 
  CDate([Created_Date.Created_Hir].MEMBER_VALUE),
           Now()
         ) <=30 
   )
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SALES_ORDER]
WHERE [~FILTER]

Comment: and it is giving me this error

Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error: argument type mismatch: parameters (java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.util.Date), actual (java.lang.String, java.lang.Double, java.util.Date)
Also i have tried changing the Created_On format to yyyy-DD-MM.

Comment: There were some missing square brackets. Try now

Comment: @SouravA this statement is specific to this question? "Don't use named set as you have in the example if you don't want to run into performance issues." .... in general named sets are good for performance

Comment: @whytheq - Hello, long time! Actually from what I've read, they should be avoided as they prevent block computation.

Comment: @SouravA definitely not true. I'm 100% sure of that.

Comment: @SouravA a dynamic named set in a cube script won't help in terms of performance. A static set is a fixed set of memory addresses (similar to an array) that is easy for the engine to find and will generally improve performance.

Comment: @SouravA clients of SSAS all use named sets extensively - do you think the guys designing Excel, SSRS or Pyramid would use named sets extensively if it had significant performance issues?

Comment: OK, just to be on the same page. You are saying the named sets declared *inside* the cube may be slow but the query scoped named sets (i.e. `WITH SET abc as.....`) are not?

Comment: @SouravA I am saying, in general, named sets are not a performance issue. Inspect the mdx generated by any client to ssas and you will see they are used a lot because they are a fixed allocation of memory and generally good for performance. In the cube script static sets are good as there is some pre-caching of these memory addresses. Dynamic sets in a cube script will not help in terms of performance or caching.

Comment: @whytheq MS tools also use a lot of subselects. And in most cases the MDX generated are poor in terms of performance. The guys designing the tool probably chose convenience over performance. In this case too, you can't argue that named set is a good approach **because** it is used by tool designers. Probably it doesn't affect that badly, but certainly to some extent, it does. What I wrote came out of instinct. But if you go through the link I mentioned couple of comments back, it does say that. Read Point # 3. (contd)

Comment: In this case, it won't affect maybe, but if this set is used later in some calculation, it might have significant impact.

Comment: I would be very interested to learn how a set *improves* the query performance, if you could pass on some references..

Comment: @SouravA ok - so your advice would be better as "be careful using named sets inside aggregation functions when constructing calculated members". RANK is so so slow without using a pre-ordered named set.

Comment: @SouravA

:( I tried the edited Version as well 
WITH
SET [~FILTER] AS
  {
  Filter 
    (DateDiff  
        (  
         "d", 
         CDate([Created_Date].[Created_Hir].MEMBER_VALUE),  
         Now()  
        ) <=30 
    ) 
    }
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS], [Measures].[CONT_AMT_NET]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SALES_ORDER]
It is giving me Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'Filter(<Logical Expression>)' 
:( .

Comment: Check your "filter" portion of code! You are missing the first argument. The first argument needs to be `[Created_Date].[Created_Hir].[Created_On].Members`

Comment: @SouravA https://books.google.com/books?id=xGR5I--lDnsC&pg=PT438&dq=tomislav+piasevoli+named+sets+inside+rank&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitn7rkivLJAhWBnBQKHXkiC-IQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=tomislav%20piasevoli%20named%20sets%20inside%20rank&f=false

Comment: After adding the 
[Created_Date].[Created_Hir].[Created_On].Members

Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error: argument type mismatch: parameters (java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.util.Date), actual (java.lang.String, java.lang.Double, java.util.Date).

Comment: Seems `CDate([Created_Date].[Created_Hir].MEMBER_VALUE)` is being treated as a double. Can you show me the member_value of a sample date?

Comment: @SouravA Added the Screen shot in Dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cjj0ieoc0v5735t/AACBP9iGw04CM3_faT5iTnqMa?dl=0

Comment: @malay no all those members will be in a single column

Comment: @SouravA and whytheq. I have followed  this linkhttp://diethardsteiner.blogspot.in/2009/10/current-date-function-on-mondrian.html
and able to pass current date but now the problem is the current date is getting passed for every column. Not able to figure it out why it is getting passed everywhere.
this is the function which I am using 
CurrentDateMember([Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On],'[yyyy-mm-dd]'). Attached mondrian_sql.log,pentaho.log  and mdxquery file on dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cjj0ieoc0v5735t/AACBP9iGw04CM3_faT5iTnqMa?dl=0.
Thanks